# Any downsides to greasing electrical connections?

Tags: connector, corrosion, edge-connector

I learned long ago, living in Buffalo NY, that any and every electrical connector I service in my cars needs grease stuffed in it or it rusts out FAST

So why don't we put any grease or other coating on card-edge connectors???

Reason I ask, I was recently put in charge of the test lab here at work (or all things electrical at least).   These test machines are predominately LabView based systems i.e. they are standard Dell PC's.   However, they only get fired up maybe once every other year or less.

I tried to run one a couple weeks ago, wouldn't boot.   Being an EE, and having serviced computers for the last 30+ years, I gravitated immediately towards pulling the cards and reinserting.   Did that a few times, and the machine booted no problem.

Which makes me think -- Should I grease the card-edge connectors in these bad boys???   Or is there something about grease and PCB's of which I'm unaware and it would cause more problems than it would prevent???

Comment: Just a guess. Bad contact may be because springs in connector lost shape, tired. Pins and socket of connectors a player usually. For reliable connection, like military stuff, plated with gold. For cheap stuff, earlier it stop work, earlier you buy new.

Comment: At least you'd have to find out if the plastics withstand the grease type. The effect on impedance matching should be negligible. Usually if the card is plugged in, the contact won't degrade too much, even if the plating on the areas not making contact begins to oxidize etc.

Comment: I've seen hydraulic fluid destroy a PCB by getting under the solder mask and taking moisture with it. Almost everything adsorbs some percentage of moisture. Dielectric grease is not intended to be used on metal contacts (it is an insulator...)  Probably best to just re-seat cards.

Comment: Automotive environment is the harshest, most destructive environment for electronics... extreme temperature variation, vibration, high voltage/fast transient from spark plugs, corrosive chemicals... that's the only reason those connections would have needed a sealant. In a normal lab environment, greasing the connections is not required and is likely to actually make things worse.

Comment: Definitely no grease, which will attract and hold dirt. There are a couple of commercial products, one called Stabilant 22, the other DeOxit, both of which claim to improve contact reliability. I can't vouch for them personally but if you need to feel you did something other than pull and reinsert the cards, you can find them on the big A.

Comment: DeOxit has 2 good spray products, a cleaner and a shield. Great for edge connectors and open switches in a dry environment. For outdoor locations, Permatex Dielectric Grease is thin-bodied and almost inert. I use it liberally for connectors, sockets and high-voltage.

Answer (score 2):

Grease has a few potential disadvantages.

1. Depending on your choice of grease it may have corrosive compounds. So make sure your selecting a grease that is fairly neutral or safe.
2. if you are too liberal with your grease, particularly around connectors, you may turn a good physical connection bad. Grease is non conductive so if it gets on and between connectors you may disrupt them from making a good connection.
3. Grease, just like any substance, can effect some electrical properties like velocity factor and capacitance. For many circuits this wont be an issue. However anything operating at higher frequencies, for example radios, this can have a significant negative effect on their operation. For anything near the output stage of an RF radio or on the transmission line or in a component in line with the transmission line, can cause noticeable losses and a reduction in transmission power.
4. It makes it damn hard to fix. You need to clean off all the grease to even properly inspect the components and even more so if you intend to solder something in an attempt to repair it. I would **not** want to be the guy who has to fix an electronics component coated in a thick coat of grease.